# SQL Inner join 2 tables to 1 question

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I have the following line of code:

```
INNER JOIN #CompanyIdT t ON e.[companyId] = t.[Value] AND c.[CompanyId] = t.[Value]
```

Does this always join to the same companyId in the t table? So could e and c ever have a different CompanyId in 1 record?

Thanks

Comment: It's a table alias.....the actual names of those tables are in no way necccessary for this question.

Comment: When joining one table, you shouldn't specify a relationship for two other tables.  That relationship should be specified on the join of those tables.

Comment: OK, but are they all aliases of the same table, or all of different tables, or what? Can you provide a full query that exemplifies your question?

Comment: It doesnt matter if they are different or the same tables. All I want to know is if e.CompanyId = t.Value = c.CompanyId no matter if they are the same table or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, e and c would never have a different value for companyID in a single record in the result set.  They will always match t.Value, thus in your resultset it will always be the case that e.companyId = c.companyId = t.Value.

Answer (score 1):

You've described a transitive relationship:

*If e.CompanyId = t.Value and c.CompanyId = t.Value, then e.CompanyId = c.CompanyId.*

Since that statement is always true, you should never have a different `CompanyId` in any row in your query results. If you have duplicate `Value` values in *t*, you *could* get multiple rows with the same `CompanyId`.